# Install apk without knowing previous key store

Tags: android

Currently am working on application which needs installation of apk through program and update it. The installation fails every time due to signature conflict.
I do not know the key store for application which was used earlier. How do I handle this?

Comment: uninstall the old version first. You can't install an update of the APK if their signatures differ.